# how to get the updated size of dynamic array in python

Tags: python-3.x

How should I edit my code?

```
import ctypes
import sys

class DynamicArray(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.n = 0 #counter 
    self.capacity = 1
    self.A = self.make_array(self.capacity)
def __len__(self):
    '''Returns the number of elements'''
    b = sys.getsizeof(self.A)
    print(b)
    return self.n
def __getitem__(self,k):
    '''Return elements in array with specified Index'''
    if not 0<=k<self.n:
        return IndexError('Index out of bounds')
    return self.A[k]
def append(self,ele):
    '''Add element in the array'''
    if self.n==self.capacity:
        self._resize(2*self.capacity)
    self.A[self.n]=ele
    self.n+=1


def _resize(self,new_cap):
    B = self.make_array(new_cap)
    for k in range(self.n):
        B[k]=self.A[k]
    self.A = B
    self.capacity = new_cap
def make_array(self,new_cap):
    '''Make a raw array using ctype module'''      
    return (new_cap*ctypes.py_object)()

arr = DynamicArray()
arr.append(1)
len(arr)
Output:
80
1
arr.append(1)
len(arr)

Output:
80
2
```

Comment: I suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: why is a list not good enough? why not numpy arrays? why reinvent the array I mean, wheel?

Answer (score 1):

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof

from doc:

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of
> object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this
> does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is
> implementation specific.
>
> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is
> accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

I hope it is clear.